# Articles devant les parties du corps

Tags: grammaire, articles

Est-ce qu'on dit : « Je me suis fracturé le genou en faisant du ski » ou « Je me suis fracturé un genou en faisant du ski »  ?

Je dirais « un » parce que cela signifie l'un des deux, mais j'ai vu des exemples comme : « Je me suis cassé la jambe » donc je suis un peu perdue...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Les deux expressions peuvent se dire sans différence de sens.

L'article indéfini est plus logique mais l'article défini plus courant (et même obligatoire pour les unijambistes...)